# ArgumentError spawning function - How do I spawn a reference to the function without running?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to test a function from my module. Whenever I try to spawn it, I get an error where the result of the function is passed to the spawn function.

```
defmodule Runner do
    def move do
      "hi"
    end
end

defmodule RunnerTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest Runner

  test "the truth" do
    assert 1 + 1 == 2
  end

  test "it increases its x position" do
    pid = spawn(Runner.move)
  end

end

  1) test it increases its x position (RunnerTest)
     test/runner_test.exs:9
     ** (ArgumentError) argument error
     stacktrace:
       :erlang.spawn("hi")
       test/runner_test.exs:10: (test)
```

I'm expecting my `Runner.move` process to be spawned, and then I could execute later to get a result. Instead, the "hi" is being passed directly into spawn.

I uncovered this by simplifying the following code:

```
defmodule Runner do
    def move do
      receive do
       {:move, x, sender} -> send sender, x + 1
     end
    end
end
```

which, when I run that, my test never finishes because as far as I can tell, move enters into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `spawn/1`, which takes anonymous function or `spawn/3`, which takes module, function name as atom and list of arguments in list.

Use:

```
spawn(fn -> Runner.move() end)
```

or

```
spawn(Runner, :move, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Argument Error at `spawn/1` function.Try this:

`spawn(&Runner.move/0)`